# PHP SQL Query for autocomplete

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a MySqL DB with a table of Properties NAMES(can be more then one word) and I want to run a query to get results for the user text inputs to use for an autocomplete field.

The query I currently use is:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE LOWER(name) LIKE '%$value%' LIMIT 7";
```

But it is not good enough.

I tried splitting the input $value but for some reason is not working:

```
$values = explode(" ", $value);

$str = "";
for($i = 0; $i < count($values); ++$i)
{
    if( $i == 0)
        $str .= "LOWER(name) LIKE '%&$values[$i]%' ";
    else
        $str .= "AND LOWER(name) LIKE '%$values[$i]%' ";
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ". $str . " LIMIT 7";
```

Do you have any suggestions?

TX in advance.

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because `$_GET` data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

**NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly in your query.

Comment: @freewind did my answer helped?

Answer (score 0):

Do `OR` instead of `AND` in your query:

```
$str .= "OR LOWER(name) LIKE '%$values[$i]%' ";
```